# How to fine tune this SQL Server query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, sql-tuning

The following query is taking more than 10 sec. How to fine tune this query?

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(A.KEY1, B.KEY1) as KEY1,
    COALESCE(A.KEY2, B.KEY2) as KEY2,
    COALESCE(A.KEY3, B.KEY3) as KEY3,
    A.NUMBER, A.SERVICE_DATE, A.SERVICE_TYPE, B.CLERK_NAME,
    (SELECT TOP 1 VALUE FROM C 
     WHERE ((A.KEY1 = C.KEY1 AND A.KEY2 = C.KEY2 AND A.KEY3 = C.KEY3) OR  
            (B.KEY1 = C.KEY1 AND B.KEY2 = C.KEY2 AND B.KEY3 = C.KEY3)) 
       AND C.CODE LIKE '*_SABC') AS XXXSVTM,
    (SELECT TOP 1 VALUE FROM C 
     WHERE ((A.KEY1 = C.KEY1 AND A.KEY2 = C.KEY2 AND A.KEY3 = C.KEY3) OR  
            (B.KEY1 = C.KEY1 AND B.KEY2 = C.KEY2 AND B.KEY3 = C.KEY3)) 
       AND C.CODE LIKE '*_SBCD') AS XXXSVCM,
    (SELECT TOP 1 VALUE FROM C 
     WHERE ((A.KEY1 = C.KEY1 AND A.KEY2 = C.KEY2 AND A.KEY3 = C.KEY3) OR  
            (B.KEY1 = C.KEY1 AND B.KEY2 = C.KEY2 AND B.KEY3 = C.KEY3)) 
       AND C.CODE LIKE '*_SCDE') AS XXXCSRV,
    (SELECT TOP 1 VALUE FROM C 
     WHERE ((A.KEY1 = C.KEY1 AND A.KEY2 = C.KEY2 AND A.KEY3 = C.KEY3) OR  
            (B.KEY1 = C.KEY1 AND B.KEY2 = C.KEY2 AND B.KEY3 = C.KEY3)) 
       AND C.CODE LIKE '*_SDEF') AS XXXSRFN,
(select TOP 1 VALUE from C where ((A.KEY1=C.KEY1 and A.KEY2=C.KEY2 and A.KEY3=C.KEY3) OR (B.KEY1 = C.KEY1 AND B.KEY2 = C.KEY2 AND B.KEY3 = C.KEY3)) and C.CODE like '*_SEFG') as XXXCSRV
,(select TOP 1 VALUE from C where ((A.KEY1=C.KEY1 and A.KEY2=C.KEY2 and A.KEY3=C.KEY3) OR (B.KEY1 = C.KEY1 AND B.KEY2 = C.KEY2 AND B.KEY3 = C.KEY3)) and C.CODE like '*_SFGH') as XXXSRLN
,(select TOP 1 VALUE from C where ((A.KEY1=C.KEY1 and A.KEY2=C.KEY2 and A.KEY3=C.KEY3) OR (B.KEY1 = C.KEY1 AND B.KEY2 = C.KEY2 AND B.KEY3 = C.KEY3)) and C.CODE like '*_SXYZ') as XXXSRCY
,(select TOP 1 VALUE from C where ((A.KEY1=C.KEY1 and A.KEY2=C.KEY2 and A.KEY3=C.KEY3) OR (B.KEY1 = C.KEY1 AND B.KEY2 = C.KEY2 AND B.KEY3 = C.KEY3)) and C.CODE like '*_SVFN') as XXXSVFN
FROM
    A 
FULL JOIN
    B ON (A.KEY1 = B.KEY1 AND A.KEY2 = B.KEY2 AND A.KEY3 = B.KEY3);
```

Update: it was typo mistake, now adjusted where clause

Comment: Get rid of all the `select top 1...` clauses, and create some sort of outer apply with a row_number or similar. Get rid of the `OR` because both sides are the same.

Comment: Also, top 1 without order by can return random results. You most likely get same results pretty often, but it might change at any point

Comment: Is this a correct condition `(A.KEY1=C.KEY1 and A.KEY2=C.KEY2 and A.KEY3=C.KEY3) OR (A.KEY1=C.KEY1 and A.KEY2=C.KEY2 and A.KEY3=C.KEY3)` or should it be B. in the right of OR

Comment: it was a typo mistake.. updated the question

Comment: @JamesZ i know select top 1 clauses are causing the issue but not sure how to enhance it. can you tell me how to outer apply with a row_number?

Comment: you can try changing the `OR` s to `UNION ALL` , `UNION ALL` leads to better performance,  please refer to https://bertwagner.com/2018/02/20/or-vs-union-all-is-one-better-for-performance/

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an INNER JOIN between A and C.
You're joining between A and C twice.
You're running 8 correlated subqueries for each record.
You're asking for the first record from C in no particular order.

This should provide the same results in less time.

```
select COALESCE(A.KEY1, B.KEY1) as KEY1
, COALESCE(A.KEY2, B.KEY2) as KEY2
, COALESCE(A.KEY3, B.KEY3) as KEY3
, A.NUMBER
, A.SERVICE_DATE
, A.SERVICE_TYPE
, B.CLERK_NAME
, min(case when C.CODE like '*_SABC' then C.VALUE) as XXXSVTM
, min(case when C.CODE like '*_SBCD' then C.VALUE) as XXXSVCM
, min(case when C.CODE like '*_SCDE' then C.VALUE) as XXXCSRV
, min(case when C.CODE like '*_SDEF' then C.VALUE) as XXXSRFN
, min(case when C.CODE like '*_SEFG' then C.VALUE) as XXXCSRV
, min(case when C.CODE like '*_SFGH' then C.VALUE) as XXXSRLN
, min(case when C.CODE like '*_SXYZ' then C.VALUE) as XXXSRCY
, min(case when C.CODE like '*_SVFN' then C.VALUE) as XXXSVFN

from A 
    inner join C on A.KEY1=C.KEY1 and A.KEY2=C.KEY2 and A.KEY3=C.KEY3
    full outer join B on A.KEY1=B.KEY1 and A.KEY2=B.KEY2 and A.KEY3=B.KEY3
;
```

If the right side of the OR in each subquery should have been `B.KEY1=C.KEY1`, etc. ...

```
select q.KEY1
, q.KEY2
, q.KEY3
, q.NUMBER
, q.SERVICE_DATE
, q.SERVICE_TYPE
, q.CLERK_NAME
, min(case when C.CODE like '*_SABC' then C.VALUE) as XXXSVTM
, min(case when C.CODE like '*_SBCD' then C.VALUE) as XXXSVCM
, min(case when C.CODE like '*_SCDE' then C.VALUE) as XXXCSRV
, min(case when C.CODE like '*_SDEF' then C.VALUE) as XXXSRFN
, min(case when C.CODE like '*_SEFG' then C.VALUE) as XXXCSRV
, min(case when C.CODE like '*_SFGH' then C.VALUE) as XXXSRLN
, min(case when C.CODE like '*_SXYZ' then C.VALUE) as XXXSRCY
, min(case when C.CODE like '*_SVFN' then C.VALUE) as XXXSVFN

from (
    select COALESCE(A.KEY1, B.KEY1) as KEY1
    , COALESCE(A.KEY2, B.KEY2) as KEY2
    , COALESCE(A.KEY3, B.KEY3) as KEY3
    , A.NUMBER
    , A.SERVICE_DATE
    , A.SERVICE_TYPE
    , B.CLERK_NAME
    
    from A 
      full outer join B on A.KEY1=B.KEY1 and A.KEY2=B.KEY2 and A.KEY3=B.KEY3
) q
  inner join C on q.KEY1=C.KEY1 and q.KEY2=C.KEY2 and q.KEY3=C.KEY3
;
```

Comment: this didn't work. it is giving more rows than the query that i mentioned in the problem.